# Нахождение ошибки в алгоритме

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада

Всем здравствуйте, задача с уже прошедшей олимпиады, не могу понять, где мой алгоритм оказался несовершенным.
Условия :

**K** черепах, имеющих номера  от 1 до **K** стоят друг за другом перед закусочной. После того, как черепаха под номером **m** забирает еду, она снова встает в очередь так, что за ней оказывается ровно **am** черепах.
Даже при бесконечном количестве блюд какие-то черепахи все равно останутся голодным. Определите, сколько черепах не получат ни одного подарка, если число обедов в закусочной бесконечно. Мой код представлен ниже :

```
n = int(input())
a = [int(elem) for elem in input().split()]
d = {}
i = 0
nh = []

for i in range(n):
    num = a[i]
    if num in d:
        d[num] += 1
        i += 1
    else:
        d[num] = num + 1
    if d[num] == n - 1:
        nh.append(d[num])


print(len(nh))
```

Пример:

```
1 2 0
```

Вывод :

```
1
```

Черепаха 1 получает подарок и становится между второй и третьей черепахой. Затем черепаха 2 начинает получать подарки и сразу возвращаться на первое место в очереди. Соответственно, черепаха 3 никогда не получит подарок.

Не понимаю, где в моем коде ошибка, не может ли кто нибудь помочь?

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, как вы решаете задачу?

Comment: Что такое `am`? Ни в задаче, ни в коде `am` нет.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в задаче есть - *за ней оказывается ровно am черепах* массив, который вводится, видимо набор этих а для каждой черепахи. Но это мои догадки

Comment: `am`, или легче воспринять  `Am`, _где A - числовое значение, на которое сдвигается черепаха, а m - "индекс" черепахи в очереди_. Я перепробовал много разных вариантов, данный основывается на переборе черепашьих сдвигов и те, кто оказываются в списке nh - никогда не получат ужин, по моим соображениям.

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что процесс завершится за n шагов. три черепахи. первая берет и встает в середину, остальные в хвост. на 4м шаге последняя получит. не?

Comment: Попробовал вариант 
`n = int(input()) - 1
print(n - list(map(int, input().split())).index(n))`
Но он выдает почему то ошибку выполнения...

Comment: вам надо крутить ходы, пока очередь не станет в том порядке, в котором она уже была. по ходу отмечая тех, кто получил. сумма остальных - то, что спрашивается в задаче. перая сложность - вставлять элементы внутрь листа. вторая -  сравнивать текущую очередь с пройденными. возможно, для второго надо использовать множества . Но я не знаю, есть ли временные ограничения. и жесткие ли они. что будет с памятью

Comment: Какие ограничения на `k`? Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Comment: какая-то фигня получается. судя по условию, никаких ограничений на к, а и м нету, поэтому может быть почти любой исход. Например к = 1. - одна черепаха, которая по любому в плюсе. К больше 1 - но первая черепаха всегда становится в начало; тогда не у дел остаются к-1 черепаха. К любое число, все черепахи становятся в конец, все получат. Бесконечная очередь черепах, и черепахи после получения становится в произв. место - бесконечное число получат и бесконечное число не получат. Не определенность, в общем. Из текущей постановки задачи можно сказать только то, что 1 черепаха точно получит. Все.

Comment: Требуется решать для десяти черепах или для миллиарда черепах? Это несколько разные задачи.

Comment: Для `k` черепах есть конфигурация (`k-2, k-3, ..., 2, 1, 0, 0`) с циклом `2^(k - 1)`. Простая симуляция очереди в поисках цикла умрёт на сорока черепахах.

Comment: я не могу понять, на основании чего сделано это утверждение: " Даже при бесконечном количестве блюд какие-то черепахи все равно останутся голодным. " ? Ведь никаких ограничений на перемещения черепах не наложено, время, которое они могут стоять в очереди не ограничено, кол-во черепах - произвольное. Чисто по теории вероятностей: при конечном числе черепах, случайном интервале смещения в очереди и неограниченных подарках при росте времени подарки будут распределяться равномерно среди всех черепах. Получается, что при заданном условии задачи ни одна черепаха не останется голодной...

Comment: @Zombotron, если первая черепаха имеет `a_m` равный `k - 1`, то она получит свой обед, но не сдвинется с места. Все остальные черепахи останутся голодными. Теория вероятности тут ни причем.

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб оживить вопрос, я написал кодом то, что вчера озвучил в комментарии. Но, вероятно, для олимпиады это медленное решение

```
# тестовые данные
from random import randint
k = 1000
# am = [1, 2, 0]
am = [randint(0, k-1) for i in range(k)]

# список, где True - получила
get = [False for i in range(k)]

# очередь
queue = tuple(i for i in range(k))
# print(queue)

# список вариантов очередей 
qlist = set()
qlist.add(queue)

while True:
    cur = queue[0]
    get[cur] = True
    queue = queue[1:len(queue)-am[cur]] + (cur,) + queue[len(queue)-am[cur]:]
    # print(queue)
    # Если такая очередь уже была, можно заканчивать 
    if queue in qlist:
        print(k - sum(get))
        break
    qlist.add(queue)
```

Comment: "    # Если такая очередь уже была, можно заканчивать " Почему?
допустим, есть очередь (1,2,3,4,5), которая меняется так: (2,1,3,4,5,) -> (1,2,3,4,5) -> (2,3,4,5,1) -> ... С какого перепугу я должен заканчивать после 2-го шага?

Comment: @Zombotron, ваша иллюстрация невозможна в условиях задачи. Текущее состояние очереди полностью определяет следующее состояние. Мы получаем траекторию на конечном множестве. Рано или поздно она зациклится.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Перечитал все еще раз комменты. Да, протупил. Нужно отдохнуть.